# Where can I find a list of all the road types in HERE Maps?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I need a list of all the road types in HERE Maps just like in OpenStreetMap but couldn't find anything in the documentation.
A list with the type name, a brief description, and an example image would be great.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway

Answer (score 0):

Which product are you looking for for those list?
There is a documentation related to HERE Map Contents via Fleet API.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/advanced-datasets-api/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html

Comment: I'm looking for Map Tile API

Comment: Are you looking for https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

In the here map documentation there is no images of the road types but you can find a little information about the road types in the road specific attribute section.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-road-properties.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).